# migrate LinearLayout to Cardview selectable

Tags: java, android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

My recyclerview is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_highlight"
    android:layout_margin="6dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleCategTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/articleNameTextView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/articleQteTextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleQteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/articleCategTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/articleNameTextView"
            android:text="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:text="@null" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**@drawable/recyclerview_highlight**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/selected_color"/>
</selector>
```

In "onBindViewHolder", I highlight it, when selected with:

```
holder.itemView.setSelected(article.isSelected());
```

All is ok BUT, for a little more visual elegance, I wanted to transform the LinearLayout into Cardview.
And when I try it, setSelected has not effect anymore. I even try to "setActivated" with state_activated but not better.

What should I modify to obtain the same type of operation? Is it at the level of the layout, the selector or the java code, and what to use instead of "selected"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly had to add a LinearLayout, inside the cardView; which is the one I `setSelected()` and the result is what I needed.